# JavaFX. AnchorPane, не могу взаимодействовать с меню

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Используя JavaFX столкнулся с проблемой, как видно на скрине, есть два элемента - меню и браузер. Оба в разных файлах, меню в основном, а браузер импортирую. Так вот собственно в чем проблема, это в том, что элементы меню активируются только когда на них наводишь выше красной линии (на скрине), если браузер привязать к меню вплотную, то с меню взаимодействовать нельзя вообще. Такое ощущение, что у элемента WebView есть невидимые края. Как исправить, что делать? Буду рад за любую подсказку!

Main.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0"
        prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="com.valeobet.client.controllers.MainController">
<children>
    <MenuBar prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="770.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
             AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="true" text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="true" text="Close"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <fx:include fx:id="browserFXML" source="browser.fxml" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"/>
</children>
```

Browser.fxml

```
<WebView fx:id="williamView" layoutX="76.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="407.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="300.0" />
```

[image: JAVAFX приложение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была тут

```
<WebView fx:id="williamView" layoutX="76.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="407.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="300.0" />
```

А конкретно `AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0"`